# Wordpress plugins: commit or not commit

Tags: wordpress, git, bitbucket

Which is better if you are not changing the plugins or if you aren't doing your own plugin, should I commit the plugin folder or add it to git.ignore file

Comment: Changing plugins vs not doing your own plugin? I have no idea what you are asking about...

Comment: when developing a theme in a team, do you recommend committing wp plugins or not

Comment: You mean how to deal with the plugin code with relation to if you change it or not? OK, I'll try to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule I'd say, **if you are making any changes** to an external plugin/library you should obviously commit it along with your solution.

**If you are not making any changes**, there is usually no reason why you'd want to do that.

However you will want to have some means of **package management**. If someone changes the version of that plugin, others need to get that same version updated upon git pull. Otherwise the dependant code may break. Hence if you are working with some kind of package manager and your plugin is treated as a package - your problem is solved. The packages themselves will be ignored by git, you will only version some kind of package configuration file and all will be updated regurarly by the package manager.

Now, if you do not have any package manager, then you will actually probably want to **consider versioning your plugin code**, even if you are not making changes to it. That way the person who updates the plugin to a new version (and it's probably going to happen with Wordpress pretty often), pushes the new version and it is updated for everyone with every git pull.

Comment: Is there a package manager for Wordpress Plugins?? what do you use?